# Why is QPixmap.load returning false?

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qtgui, qpixmap

In the following code `getPixmap` returns a `NULL` pixmap at which point the program tries to load a pixmap from a resource. For some reason, on Ubuntu 11.10 this works fine, but under Ubuntu 13.10 it returns false. Why?

```
QPixmap pix = getPixmap(photo);
if (pix.isNull()){
    if (!pix.load(":/resources/images/user/Unknown.jpg")){
        printf("picture failed to load\n");
        fflush(0);
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work with relative path to a jpg on your filesystem? Have you tried assigning the format explicitly? Btw, exiting with 0 for failure is weird.

Comment: It does not with with a relative path to a file, absolute path to a file, or with the format explicitly set. Could there be a library missing maybe?

Comment: Hmm, and fromImage works if you load the file into a QImage?

Comment: Nope, if I try to load the picture via `QImage img(filename);` then `img.isNull()` return true. (And yes I checked that the file exists via `QFile::exists(filename)`).

Comment: Have you tried at least 2-3 very different images, i.e. different formats, etc? Which Qt exactly are you using?

Comment: @LaszloPapp I've tried with other images and they dont work. I've tried that same image on a different machine and it works. Qt 4.8.5

Comment: Define "other images".

Comment: different jpeg images, havent tried png or gif. ill try them if you think itll make a difference. Interesting, it correctly loads a png but not a jpeg.

Comment: Note that you are not using jpeg in the following code, but jpg. Are you sure you did not make a typo for the format. Does it work with gif Also, are you sure the "jpg" is actually a "jpg", and not a png loaded as "jpg". Please make sure about it in a proper viewer.

Comment: Also, do you have the jpeg enumerated in /usr/lib/qt/mkspecs/qconfig.pri or wherever that is on your distribution? Do you have the jpeg plugin installed? `apt-cache search jpeg | grep qt` and `dpkg -l \*jpeg\*`. The path is `/usr/lib/qt/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.so` for me with Qt 5 on Archlinux. You must have something similar.